# mysql connection rest service

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, api, methods

Trying to make a simple rest service. The rest service is for pulling up a table from a local database. This rest service a want to make available for an android app.

Having trouble getting passed .then block. Tried catching the error but with no success. How do you catch the error if it's going wrong in the first .then 
The below piece of code is the db.js, and sets up the connection to the database.

```
var sqlDb = require("mysql");
var settings = require("../settings");

exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {

var conn = new sqlDb.createConnection(settings.dbConfig);
conn.connect()
// !! Error unhandled
.then(function () {
        var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
        req.query(sql)
            .then(function (recordset) {
                callback(recordset);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(null, err);
            });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(null, err);
    });
};
```

After setting up connection the below piece of code is executed. With error handling.

```
var db = require("../core/db");

exports.getList = function (req, resp) {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM employees", function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            // throws back error to web
            resp.writeHead(500, "Internal Error", { "Content-Type": 
            "application/json" });
            resp.write(JSON.stringify({ data: "ERROR occurred:" + err }));
        } else {
            resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
            resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        resp.end();
    });
};
```

Made a separated js file for settings such as database. Tested my connection to the db on a same way. Excluded that problem but it keeps returning an error unhandled on the first .then. I'm not familiar with methods till now.

I think I found the problem. new sqlDb.Request(conn); The .Request is not available when using mysql. But how can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you catch() an error it will not be caught again without returning a new rejection. Like this:

```
conn.connect()
.then(function () {
        var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
        // note the "return" here
        return req.query(sql)
            .then(function (recordset) {
                callback(recordset);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(null, err);
                // note the line below
                return Promise.reject(err)
            });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(null, err);
    });
};
```

PS. Do you really need the callback(), why not use the Promise?

Comment: I took out the callback and put in the promise but keep getting exception unhandled. It's on the .then

Comment: I think I found the problem. new sqlDb.Request(conn); The.Request is not available when using mysql. But how can I fix this

Comment: Remove "new" from both places then. I didn't react to these before but I really don't think you should use new there.

Comment: Took out the new but it still hangs on the .then. I'm also not familiar with the Promise method. I will try putting the query and error handling in the same file.

Comment: What mysql library are you using? I don't think there is any support for promises on https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql, I have wrapped it myself to use promises instead of callbacks.